# Javascript file how not to display API key

Tags: javascript, youtube, api-key

I am trying to create the Codeacademy [Searching for YouTube Videos](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-intermediate-en-757J2/0/2?curriculum_id=50ecb8d45f787a6332000042) using GitHub Pages.

They have in search.js

```
function onYouTubeApiLoad() {
    // This API key is intended for use only in this lesson.
    gapi.client.setApiKey('_API_KEY_');

    // Add code here to test out showResponse():

}
```

My repository is public. Is there any way to hide the API key I will use?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" way to store sensitive keys such as your YouTube API key is to store them as environment variables on the server.

Instead of storing your key as a string literal to `onYouTubeApiLoad()`, you could read the environment variable and store it in a global or in another convenient location, as below.

```
const youtubeSecret = process.env.YOUTUBE_SECRET;

function onYouTubeApiLoad() {
    // This API key is intended for use only in this lesson.
    gapi.client.setApiKey(youtubeSecret);

    // Add code here to test out showResponse():

}
```

Creating and storing an environment variable is another matter, and depends on the system you're using as well as how you're hosting it. In the simplest case, if you're running this program locally on a Linux/MacOS/BSD, you can type `export YOUTUBE_SECRET=(your secret key)` into your terminal before running the program, or add it directly into your .bashrc file. (Better yet, you could read it from a file in your .bashrc.) If you're hosting your program in the cloud (e.g. AWS, Heroku), the process will be somewhat different. There are plenty of other answers which go into the specifics of how to do that.

The other good way of doing this is to store your secret key in its own file, and add that file to your .gitignore. Then you could use the Node.js `fs` module to read it and store it an a variable as above.

Comment: so have the API key stored in a file for example config.js and in the .gitignore file have config.js?

Comment: You can store the key "raw," that is, not in a javascript file, and then use something like this: `const youtubeSecret = fs.readFileSync('./youtubeSecret.txt');`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript isn't inherently secure in that aspect. Everything you write is exposed. Your key is going to be visible to others. Your best bet is not to publish your key in your repository and regenerate your api keys periodically. You will not be able to access environment variables from client side scripts either. You'll need an application on the server side and ultimately it will expose your key.

Comment: If I don't publish my key in the repository how will the website work? Function onYouTubeApiLoad() needs an API key.

Comment: As github pages states in their documentation "Warning: GitHub Pages sites are publicly available on the internet, even if their repositories are private. If you have sensitive data in your Page repository, you may want to remove it before publishing."

Comment: so it seems there is no way to use the same example from Codeacademy without exposing my API key?

Comment: You can always run the examples without publishing them somewhere like Github Pages. JsFiddle and other places work excellent. Is there any particular reason why you need to publish this project to a public repo?

Comment: Yes, trying to do a website that involves retrieving YouTube links for my own consumption and a few friends. Github Pages seems to be the ideal place as it's free and easy to use.

Comment: Unfortunately Git hub pages offers no privacy on a per use basis. They may not be your favorite place for this. They also aren't necessarily there for hosting a production level site. However just keep an eye on the api key usage, roll your keys often, and you'll be fine if you really want to stay with github pages.